# Inserting javascript into sharepoint editform.aspx

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, date, encoding

I want to customize my sharepoint datepicker to prevent user from selecting past date. I have found the following code on this website

```
$(function () {
            $("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker(
            {
             minDate: +0,
            });
        });
```

but I am not sure where to insert this script. From what research I've done, it needs to be inserted in editform.aspx. I do not know where in the current script to place it, at the end of whats already there? I found I could not paste when I tried to paste it to the end. I am a complete novice at coding so any help would be greatly appreciated. I use SharePoint Designer 2010 and Workspace 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use content editor web part to insert javascript. see [this](http://sharepointadam.com/2010/08/31/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/) link you can google content editor webpart for more examples.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if the correct formula above is correct for restricting the choice of past dates i.e. is minDate: +0 correct? Also how do I link it to the datepicker itself? is ("<%=TextBox1.ClientId %>") just a generic name and do I have to change it specifically to link to my datepicker?

Comment: I am not an expert of jquery. If you are facing issue in jquery then i would suggest you to raise separate question for that and tag it for jquery/javascript. sorry for that

Comment: How do you do that in Sharepoint Designer? The Content Editor is not available in our site.